# avoid receiving error when there is not .caption ( or user.id or ..... ) in the update Parameters ( argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable )

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I use python-telegram-bot to create a bot .
I  want to check the caption of the photo which my bot received 
I use

```
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.photo,image)
```

I check the caption

```
if update.message.caption == 'something ':
    do something
```

when photo have caption code works fine the problem is when the photo have no caption I receive this error

```
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

basically it can't find `update.message.caption` in the Parameters. When the photo has a caption there is `.caption` Parameter in the update, but when user sends the photo without the caption then there is no `.caption` Parameters in the update

how can I avoid this error? or how can i check if there is 'caption' Parameter in the update or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about what you're trying to do here, however in this case I'd try to catch the exception thrown in case no caption is there, something like this;

```
try:    
    caption = update.message.caption
    #do something with caption
except:
    #Do something else in case no caption is there
```

Comment: when there is photo with caption update will be like

'update_id': 14515617, 'message': {'message_id': 489, 'date': .......  'caption': 'caption test ', .............

Comment: You mean your information is stored in a dictionary? Can you give an example of how your data looks like?

Comment: when there is no caption in the photo then update will be like 

'update_id': 14515617, 'message': {'message_id': 489, 'date': .................

because of that '.caption' will be not in the update and i receive the error
what i want to do is to check if 'update.message.caption' is exist in update or not

Comment: here is the code 
'def image (bot, update):'
'    if update.message.caption == ' something' :'
'        print('photo caption in something')'

Comment: Did you try the try/except code? Basically you can try doing something with your caption and if it fails it means there's no caption...

Comment: there will be no difference when it check the update for .caption then it gives the error  it will fail but with error

Comment: Not if you catch the exception, you can do something in case there's no caption....

Comment: You should use `except TypeError:`. A simple `except` will catch all the exceptions, and in-case some other exception occurs, you would not be able to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

it is Solved and this is how i do it

```
  if hasattr(update.message,'caption'):
     print('yes there is ') 
  else:
     print('there is no caption')
```

I hope this helps you